# C # Regex Find and Replace With Wildcard Between Strings

Tags: c#, regex, replace, find, wildcard

I have a txt file that I need to break out line by line with matched strings that contain wildcards between. For example, my first line needs to match on ISA with a wildcard and then match again on a ~ It would be something like this: ISA WILDCARD ~ I want to replace it with the entire string I just matched on with \r\n afterwards to linebreak.

I currently have some code to do something like this but it only matches on a ~ and replaces it with a ~ and linebreaks afterwards. I just need some help getting set on the right path. Here is the code so everyone can see what I'm working with.

```
public static void ReturnFirstLine() //ReplaceAsterik
{
    // where to start your directory walk
    var directoryToTraverse = @"\\filepath";

    // what files to open
    var fileTypeToOpen = "*.820";

    // what to look for
    var patternToMatch = @"/~";

    var regExp = new Regex(patternToMatch);

    // the new content
    var patternToReplace = "~\r\n";

    // get all the files we want and loop through them to replace
    foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(directoryToTraverse, fileTypeToOpen, SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    {
        // open, replace, overwrite
        var contents = File.ReadAllText(file);
        var newContent = regExp.Replace(contents, patternToReplace);
        File.WriteAllText(file, newContent);            
    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't quite understand your question, although i've got a regex pattern to match a line with the wildcard, which is "**ISA (.*) ~**"

Comment: If you would like to REPLACE the words "WILDCARD" in your example string, use this one: (?<=ISA)(.*)(?=~)

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please post an actual sample of what should match, what should NOT match, what portion of what DOES match should be replaced and WHAT is should be replaced with.

Comment: Hey sorry for the oddly worded question, what you suggested for the wildcard worked! However, I ran into another issue, and that there is many ~ throughout my txt file. Do you know of a way to match on "ISA (.*) ~" with the ~ being the first and then replace with everything I matched on and the linebreak using \r\n?

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to process EDI transaction sets.  What are you trying to replace inside these?  Perhaps you should use code designed to [parse EDI](https://x12parser.codeplex.com/).